# Async branch and sync branch meet using Angular Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, branch, observable

Let us say we have a simple pseudo code snippet like this:

```
if (myCondition){
  // Async branch
  myObservable
    .somethingAsync()
    .subscribe(x => {
      doSomething(x);
    });
} else {
  // Sync branch
  somethingSync();
}
continueBothHere();
```

So, an async branch and a sync branch, where *continueBothHere()* always gets executed after the if statement.
Let us say that *continueBothHere()* does not need any input from either branch.

*How do I implement this using Observables?*

I suppose I want to define an Observable *before* the if statement, so I can use it *after* the if statement to join the branches? But could that be combined with the observable in the true branch? And what do I say for that Observable inside the false branch, if anything? And maybe this could be implemented without using an if statement?

---

Just to be clear: in the true branch I want the execution of *doSomething(x)* to be followed by the execution of *continueBothHere()*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I deal with `observable` which I want to include to asynchronous chain or both sync and async operations, which should have the same next steps, I usually start with `new Promise`. This way you can easily make your code asynchronous and handle data inside `then` blocks:

```
new Promise (resolve => {
  if (myCondition){
    // Async branch
    myObservable
      .somethingAsync()
      .take(1)
      .subscribe(x => {
        resolve(doSomething(x));
      });
  } else {
    // Sync branch
    resolve(somethingSync());
  }
})
.then(data => {
  // "data" will contain the result of "doSomething(x)" or "somethingSync()" execution, depending on "if" statement
  continueBothHere();
})
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, this is how we solve the problem in angularjs. Observables, being a superset of Promises regarding syntax and capabilities, I was hoping for a possible alternative mechanism. Maybe one that just uses the the variable (*myObservable*) in the true branch, to **also** control the overall program flow?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap sync branch into Observable and subscribe to result anywhere.

```
checkCondition():Observable<any>{
 if (myCondition){
  // Async branch
  return myObservable.somethingAsync();
 } else {
  // Sync branch
  return Observable.of(somethingSync());
}

this.checkCondition.subscribe(result=>continueBothHere());
```

Comment: Great, but how can I use this idea as part of a sequence of statements inside a method? Taking the if statement out and making it into a separate method may work in some cases, but in my scenario I have: statementA; if statement; statementB. So your checkCondition() definition and the following call of the method would have to replace "if statement" - which I think you cannot do?

Comment: Correction: the last part of my first comment should read: ...I have: statementA; if statement; continueBothHere(); statementB. So your checkCondition() definition and the following call of the method would have to replace "if statement; continueBothHere();" - which I think you cannot do?

Comment: You need to separate method anywhere аnd add result as parametr to continueBothHere(result).

Comment: It's a bad practice when one method contains a synchronous code, an asynchronous code, something else, and maybe something else... If you don`t wont to use if, you can try to use [filter](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-filter) and [map](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-map) But I did not see a real code and it's hard to tell how to solve the problem.